# How to get highest/lowest ordinal value of user defined subrange type in Free Pascal

Tags: types, freepascal

How to get highest/lowest ordinal value of user defined subrange type in Free Pascal?

Let's say we have this defined:

```
type
  LowChars = 'a'..'z';
```

And I need to get the highest/lowest value of the type.

`Low(Ord(LowChars))` gives me the the lowest value of Char type, which is not what I want.

Thank you.

Comment: Surely it should just be `Low(LowChars)`, no ?

Comment: @PaulR I thought so, but it says Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "LowChars", expected "QWord"

Comment: @PaulR thank you for the idea, I had it composed badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, mystery solved `Ord(Low(LowChars))` works.